# How to get variable from route/web.php to controller

Tags: javascript, laravel, variables, controller, routes

I built a select box and an `onclick` event with JavaScript. Here is my JavaScript part which receives one value.

```
<script>
    $('#spiele').on('change', function(e){
        console.log(e);

        var spielID = e.target.value;

        //ajax
        $.get('/spieler-table?spielID=' + spielID, function(data){

            //success data
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

After that, the selected value comes to the `route/web.php`

```
Route::get('/spieler-table', function(){
    $spielID = Input::get('spielID');
    echo $spielID;
});
```

I see the correct deleted value in the console.
But the next step for me is, to put the variable to the controller 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Spieler;

```
class SpielerController extends Controller
{
        public function getSpieler(/*var*/){
            //Here I need the var!!!
        }
}
```

What I have to do to get the variable in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

route:

```
Route::get('/spieler-table',  'SpielerController@getSpieler');
```

controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SpielerController extends Controller
{
    public function getSpieler(Request $request){
        $spielID = $request->get('spielID');
        dd($spielID);
    }
}
```

or

js:

```
$.get('/spieler-table/' + spielID, function(data)
```

route:

```
Route::get('/spieler-table/{spielID}',  'SpielerController@getSpieler');
```

controller:

```
class SpielerController extends Controller
{
    public function getSpieler(int $spielID){
         dd($spielID);
    }
}
```